Using a question mark as a title separator for subsequent citations in BibLaTeX
I am working on a project using LaTeX and BibLaTeX with the SBL style and I want to use a question mark as a separator for subtitles other than the default colon.
I have tried defining a custom separator for the subtitle and redefining the \subtitlepunct command to use a question mark, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.
Here is my current LaTeX code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=sbl,backend=biber]{biblatex}

% Define custom separator for subtitle
\newcommand*{\addquestion}{\addpunct{?\space}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,thesis,unpublished]{title}{%
  \iffieldundef{subtitle}
    {#1\isdot}
    {#1\subtitlepunct\printfield{subtitle}}}

\renewcommand*{\subtitlepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\subtitlepunct}{\addquestion\space}

\begin{filecontents}[force,noheader]{\jobname.bib}
    @article{cleary1993,
        title = {After the {{Frontier}}: {{Problems}} with {{Political Economy}} in the {{Modern Brazilian Amazon}}},
        author = {Cleary, David},
        date = {1993-05},
        journaltitle = {Journal of Latin American Studies},
        volume = {25},
        number = {2},
        pages = {331--349}
    }

    @article{corrigan2018,
        title = {How Much Is Social Media Worth? {{Estimating}} the Value of {{Facebook}} by Paying Users to Stop Using It},
        author = {Corrigan, Jay R. and Alhabash, Saleem and Rousu, Matthew and Cash, Sean B.},
        date = {2018-12-19},
        journaltitle = {PLOS ONE},
        volume = {13},
        number = {12},
        pages = {e0207101}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\section*{Test Bibliography}

Here is a citation test\footcite{cleary1993, corrigan2018}.

Cite them again\footcite{corrigan2018, cleary1993}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}

The second subsequent footnote citation is as follows:
Corrigan et al., How Much Is Social Media Worth? Estimating the Value of Facebook by Paying Users to Stop Using It; Cleary, After the Frontier.

But the expected result should be as follows, e.g. with the question mark as the separator:
Corrigan et al., How Much Is Social Media Worth; Cleary, After the Frontier.

How can I update the code to achieve this output?

öh, this sounds like a misunderstanding. The subtitle should be given as an extra field in the bib file.

biblatex does not analyse the contents of the title field to figure out which bit is the title and which is subtitle. Instead you have to use the title and subtitle field to supply that info in the data. The \subtitlepunct is then inserted by biblatex between title and subtitle when they are printed. This command is not used to understand the structure the data in the input.
The following will give sensible output.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=sbl,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{cleary1993,
  title        = {After the Frontier},
  subtitle     = {Problems with Political Economy in the Modern {Brazilian Amazon}},
  author       = {Cleary, David},
  date         = {1993-05},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Latin American Studies},
  volume       = {25},
  number       = {2},
  pages        = {331--349}
}
@article{corrigan2018,
  title        = {How Much Is Social Media Worth?},
  subtitle     = {Estimating the Value of {Facebook} by Paying Users to Stop Using It},
  author       = {Corrigan, Jay R. and Alhabash, Saleem and Rousu, Matthew and Cash, Sean B.},
  date         = {2018-12-19},
  journaltitle = {PLOS ONE},
  volume       = {13},
  number       = {12},
  eid          = {e0207101},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Here is a citation test\footcite{cleary1993, corrigan2018}.

Cite them again\footcite{corrigan2018, cleary1993}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}


In some circumstances it can be useful to use the title and shorttitle field instead. You would give the full title in the title field and shorttitle would contain the shortened bit of the title you want to see in subsequent citations. Usually the title+subtitle approach is sufficient (and more natural) for simple title with subtitle cases, but your mileage may vary.

Thanks. But without the shorttitle or subtitle field in my example, why the subsequent citation @cleary1993 can omit title part after the colon automatically?

@TomBen biblatex-sbl has a feature to automatically 'cut' the title field at the colon and put everything before the colon into the shorttitle field. This is a non-standard feature and while it could obviously be extended for cases with ? as well (assuming a title can never contain : or ? that does not separate the title from the subtitle) I would not rely on it and instead mark up the fields properly in the source .bib file.

Thanks for your clear explanation.
